# SQL performance issue : find a route

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm struggling with performance issue on my of my SQL query

I have a train journey traveling 5 stations named "A - B - C - D - E".
A passenger book a ticket for only "B - C - D" ride.
I need to retrieve all stations my passengers goes to.

What I have stored :

```
JOURNEY
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| id | departure_datetime | arrival_datetime  | departure_station | arrival_station |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1 | 2018-01-01 06:00   | 2018-01-01 10:00  | A                 | E               |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+

BOOKING
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| id | journey_id | departure_station | arrival_station |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |          1 | B                 | D               |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+

LEG
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| id | journey_id | departure_station | arrival_station |  departure_time  |   arrival_time   |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 |          1 | A                 | B               | 2018-01-01 06:00 | 2018-01-01 07:00 |
|  2 |          1 | B                 | C               | 2018-01-01 07:00 | 2018-01-01 08:00 |
|  3 |          1 | C                 | D               | 2018-01-01 08:00 | 2018-01-01 09:00 |
|  4 |          1 | D                 | E               | 2018-01-01 09:00 | 2018-01-01 10:00 |
+----+------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Only way I found to retrieve stations is :

```
select b.id as booking, l.departure_station, l.arrival_station
from JOURNEY j
inner join BOOKING b on j.id = b.journey_id
inner join LEG dl on (j.id = dl.journey_id and b.departure_station = dl.departure_station)
inner join LEG al on (j.id = al.journey_id and b.arrival_station = al.arrival_station)
inner join LEG l on (j.id = l.journey_id and l.departure_time >= dl.departure_time and l.arrival_time <= al.arrival_time)
where b.id = 1
```

But my LEG table is huge and doing this 3 joins on is very slow. Is there a way I can join only one time LEG table to increase performance ?

Intended return :

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| booking_id | departure_station | arrival_station |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|          1 | B                 | C               |
|          1 | C                 | D               |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I work on mariadb 12.2 so i have access to window function but i'm still not very comfortable with it.

Thanks.

EDIT : create tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `BOOKING` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `journey_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `departure_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `arrival_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `JOURNEY` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `departure_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `arrival_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `departure_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `arrival_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `LEG` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `journey_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `departure_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `arrival_station` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `departure_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `arrival_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: What is the intended result for the example you gave?

Comment: I added to question, sorry for missing...

Comment: Please provide your `CREATE TABLE` for each table please

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Check my answer please. Create indexes you need.

Comment: Why not chuck a few INSERTS in there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like your DB schema. 
But in your particular case, since you have your query working good for you.
I would just create few indexes too speed up execution.
In general there is nothing wrong when you need to join table few times to itself.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a467/1

Try just add 4 indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX journey ON BOOKING (journey_id);
CREATE INDEX arrival ON LEG (journey_id, arrival_station);
CREATE INDEX departure ON LEG (journey_id, departure_station);
CREATE INDEX d_a_time ON LEG (journey_id, departure_time, arrival_time);
```

And run your query again, it should be much faster when using indexes.

Comment: It's a very lightweight model of my database schema. Actually, stations in LEG, JOURNEY and BOOKING are only foreign keys id pointing a station table.
Thanks you for your answer, I will try with those specific ids

Comment: My answer is not about ids but about indexes.

Comment: Thanks you those indexes on departure and arrival where missing, it's a lot better now

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/):

```
WITH leg_cte as
(
    SELECT l.* FROM leg l
        JOIN booking b
            ON l.journey_id = b.journey_id
    WHERE b.id = 1
)

SELECT
    b.id as booking, 
    l.departure_station, 
    l.arrival_station
FROM
    booking b
    JOIN leg_cte dl
        ON b.departure_station = dl.departure_station
    JOIN leg_cte al 
        ON b.arrival_station = al.arrival_station
    JOIN leg_cte l 
        ON l.departure_time >= dl.departure_time AND l.arrival_time <= al.arrival_time

WHERE b.id = 1
```

Comment: Cool i like this suggestion. I'm trying it tomorrow for sure, thanks.

Comment: Note: requires MySQL 8 or later

Comment: Do we still need `WHERE b.id = 1` at the end of the query? I feel like we already make it when CTE.

Comment: And finally looking at this approach I really doubt that it will bring any performance improvement. To me it makes thing even slower because you use `leg_cte` kind *view* or *temporary table* instead of basic core table `LEG` which is much better for Mysql.

Comment: Or MariaDB 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try it `left join` and use `REGEXP` to filiter departure_station and arrival_station

```
select T3.id booking_id , T1.departure_station,T1.arrival_station
from LEG T1
left join JOURNEY T2 on T1.`journey_id` = T2.`id`
  and (T1.`departure_time` >= T2.`departure_datetime` and T1.`arrival_time` <= T2.`arrival_datetime`)
left join BOOKING T3 on  T3.`id` = T2.`id` 
    and T1.departure_station REGEXP (CONCAT('[',T3.departure_station , '-' , T3.arrival_station,']' ))
    and T1.arrival_station REGEXP (CONCAT('[',T3.departure_station , '-' , T3.arrival_station,']' ))
where T1.journey_id = 1 and T3.id is not null ;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53bf4a/48/0)

```
| booking_id | departure_station | arrival_station |
|------------|-------------------|-----------------|
|          1 |                 B |               C |
|          1 |                 C |               D |
```

---

**Test DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE JOURNEY
    (`id` int, `departure_datetime` datetime, `arrival_datetime` datetime, `departure_station` varchar(1), `arrival_station` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO JOURNEY
    (`id`, `departure_datetime`, `arrival_datetime`, `departure_station`, `arrival_station`)
VALUES
    (1, '2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 10:00:00', 'A', 'E')
;


CREATE TABLE BOOKING
    (`id` int, `journey_id` int, `departure_station` varchar(1), `arrival_station` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO BOOKING
    (`id`, `journey_id`, `departure_station`, `arrival_station`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'B', 'D')
;


CREATE TABLE LEG
    (`id` int, `journey_id` int, `departure_station` varchar(1), `arrival_station` varchar(1), `departure_time` datetime, `arrival_time` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO LEG
    (`id`, `journey_id`, `departure_station`, `arrival_station`, `departure_time`, `arrival_time`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A', 'B', '2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 'B', 'C', '2018-01-01 07:00:00', '2018-01-01 08:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 'C', 'D', '2018-01-01 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 'D', 'E', '2018-01-01 09:00:00', '2018-01-01 10:00:00')
;
```

Comment: Why do you think that is faster?

Comment: @Alex Asker join three time  LEG

Comment: Sorry i did not specify but station name are not specifically by alphabetical order, it can be anything. On the other hand departure time is always at the same time of the previous arrival time. You answer gave me some ideas, thanks.